# Missing some packages?

Tags: packages, version-7

I am trying to use a program written by someone else.  When I run the program, I am supposed to get a number as a result, however, what I got is some complicated result with "InterpolatingFunction" and "Developer`PackedArrayForm".  I am wondering whether there is any package I should load in that causes this problem?  I upload the program I am trying to run in the following link:
https://user.iter.org/filesharing/?uid=d2bc26f7-c4c4-406b-8337-cb2d26772db4

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I tested your notebook with *Mathematica* 9.0.1 on Linux and everything works as expected. Here is a screenshot of what you try to do. Note that I only adapted the package location to my download folder

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your help!  I am using Mathematica 7, so I think that is probably the problem...  Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe @Mr.Wizard can try this for you as he has version 7 too.

Comment: I'll try this soon.